# Does the $\lim_{(x,y) \to (\infty,\infty)} ({x+y})/({x^2 - xy + y^2})$ exists?

Tags: limits

Can you help me with counting this limense. Any hints, ... etc, If It exists.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $\left|\dfrac{x+y}{x^2-xy+y^2}\right| \le \dfrac{2|x+y|}{x^2+y^2}\le \dfrac{4}{|x+y|}$ By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for the second one and $x^2 -xy + y^2 \ge \dfrac{x^2+y^2}{2}$ for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

What about evaluating the limits by using substitution $x=1/X, y=1/Y$ so that

$lim_{(X,Y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{XY(X+Y)}{X^2-XY+Y^2}$

Can you proceed from here?